# Divisibility of a sum in a ring

Tags: ring-theory

I can't seem to recall, or find anywhere online an answer to this.

If you have a ring $R$, and elements $a,b,c\in R$, what conditions do you need on $R$ to have $a\mid b+c\implies a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$? I don't think it holds in general for any ring, but I'm struggling to find out when it does hold - is being an integral domain enough?

### Edit

What I'm really trying to do is show a specific ideal $\left(a(x,y),b(x,z)\right)$ in a polynomial ring $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$ is prime. I thought that the way to do it would be take $f,g\in\mathbb C[x,y,z]$ so that $fg=ra(x,y)+sb(x,z)$ (that is the product is in the ideal). I thought I'd show that $f$ (or $g$) would have to divide both $a(x,y)$ and $b(x,y)$ but given the comments this seems incorrect. What would be the way to go about this problem?

Comment: Do you mean, what conditions on $R$ will ensure that *for every* $a,b,c\in R$, if $a\mid b+c$ then $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$?

Comment: Well obviously, being an integral domain isn't enough since it doesn't work in $\Bbb Z$. $2\mid 1+1 \not\implies 2 \mid 1 \land 2 \mid 1$

Comment: @xavierm02 True - apparently I'm too tired to be thinking straight

Comment: Well, let $a\in R$ be a non-invertible element, let $u\in R^*$ be invertible and let $b\in R$ be such that $a\mid b$. Then $a\mid b=(b-u)+u$ implies that $a\mid u$, i.e. there is $c\in R$ such that $ac=u$, but then there is $v\in R$ such that $uv=1$, so $acv=1$, so $a$ is invertible. Absurd. So it seems that $R$ is a field...

Comment: What do you mean by specific? Your $a(x,y)$ and $b(x,z)$ are *particular* polynomial? If that's the case, it could be useful to tell what polynomials…